# accsseing variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't figure out how to accessed `percEntage` variable from `$("#checkDate").on("click", function();`.

```
var percEntage;

function move() {

    move.called = true; 
    var elem = document.getElementById("checkDate");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            ==>>percEntage  = document.getElementById("checkDate").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }   
}

$("#checkDate").on("click", function(){

    var dateObject = $("#arrivalsDate").datepicker('getDate');  
    if(!dateObject){
        $("#arrivalsDate").effect( "shake", {times:4}, 1000 );      
    }else{
        move();
        ==>alert(percEntage);
        if(percEntage=="100%"){
            //do something
        }       
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to define it in a more global scope so it can be seen from more places.

Comment: The variable is set in an interval. You'll have to move the check inside the interval callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what others have written, you don't need either defining in a more global scope (that is global enough!) or using `window.percEntage`.

Actually, nothing prevents `$("#checkDate").on("click", ...` from accessing the percEntage variable.

Have a look to the following snippet containing a simplified version of your code:

```js
var percEntage;

function move() {
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            $( "#checkDate" ).css( "width", width + '%');
            $( "#checkDate" ).html( width + "%" )
            percEntage = $( "#checkDate" ).html();
        }
    }   
}

$("#checkDate").on("click", function(){
    move();
    alert(percEntage);
    if(percEntage=="100%"){
     alert( "Completed!" );
        //do something more
    }       
});
```

```css
#checkDate{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="checkDate">Check date</button>
```

The reason why you get an 'undefined' alert the first time you click on `checkDate` is that `setInterval` hasn't started yet. From then on you get the correct percentage.

But, of course, if you click again on `checkDate` the element will return to its original size and the interval will be restarted (not sure if that is what you want). Also, nothing will happen when the element reaches the 100% width at least you click on it again.

If you need that something happens automatically when `checkDate` reaches the 100% you need to be checking (as JJJ has stated) inside the interval. Something like:

```
function checkDateCompleted() {
    // do something great here!
}

function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        checkDateCompleted();
    } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
        percEntage  = document.getElementById("checkDate").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your effort David! you gave me a clear vision to come out of this locked situation, It works following second method as JJJ has stated.

Answer (score 0):

use window.percEntage everywhere in your code instead of percEntage so that you can make sure you are referring to the same percEntage every time.